# What exactly is Svecchachara? Does it justify evil?

Tags: nath, svecchacara

I saw on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svecchacara) various definitions of Svecchachara, acting as one likes, arbitrariness, acting without restraint, "behaving as one desires" or "in accordance with one's will (iccha)", "a way of life where one acts as one wishes and does what is right in one's own eyes. Doing one's own Will."

But my question is, does svecchachara mean you can do anything you want to do even if it's an evil deed like murder, theft, rape, etc.?